# ASP.NET LinkButton not firing in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

I have a dilemma, where an ASP.NET `LinkButton` with an `OnCommand` property doesn't fire in Chrome or Edge when it is clicked.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="editFlightScheduleHeaderLinkButton" runat="server" 
     OnCommand="editFlightScheduleHeaderAndNotesLinkButton_Click" 
     CommandArguments="test">
```

And here is the C# code

```
protected void editFlightScheduleHeaderAndNotesLinkButton_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    flightScheduleTimer = false;
    PopulateFlightScheduleHeaderAndNotesOnDialog();
    CommandHiddenField.Value = "editFlightScheduleHeaderLinkButton_Click"
}
```

This only works in Internet Explorer, but not for Chrome, Firefox, or Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

About the only error I see is you using
CommandArguments in place of the
correct CommandArgument. Give that a try.